# Wordpress: How to create frontend table using data from backend DB table

Tags: wordpress, html-table, frontend

I am relatively new to WP, and am trying to figure out if the following can be done, or if a plugin exists?

I am looking to save data (500K+ rows) into a SQL table (maybe a new table in WP database), and then render the results on a page (frontend) using some basic JS and CSS. Because of the size of data, I am not sure if I should use a plugin that imports from CSV/JSON and would it slow down the site.

Do I have to go all the way and create models and views and then render to an HTML, or is there an easy hack available?

As the last resort, I am also thinking of creating the table part using Flask and SQlite and use it as main domain, and WP blog as subdomain (don't know if it will impact SEO).

Request guidance from experts. TIA

Answer (score 0):

There are [plugins to handle table work](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/table/). Use your favorite internet search engine to find them. You'll have to experiment with various plugins to get one that meets your needs if you go that route.

There two questions here.

One is how to render a table on the front end. If you do this yourself , your best bet is to create a [plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) that defines a [shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/).  When you write php code for that shortcode's handler, you will include code to read and render the table. You'll probably render it as an ordinary html `<table>`.

Then, you'll use WordPress's content editor to create a post, or a page, that contains your shortcode. When a visitor views the post or page, your shortcode handler runs and delivers the table you want.

The WordPress plugin API also gives you a way to [enqueue css](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and [Javascript](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to your pages. And, jquery is an inherent part of WordPress's page loads. WordPress also contains most of jqueryUI. That's handy, because there's a really nice jquery-based plugin called [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) that will get your users some convenient features like pagination and sorting.

The second question is how to load that data into a table. The easy way would be to do it outside WordPress, with a SQL file or some other program to bulk-load it. But if you do it inside WordPress, you'll do it from an administrative page.

If you need to be able to add, update, or delete table entries from the front end, that's going to be some work.

Explaining all this in detail is far outside the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.